# JavaScript remove multiple spaces in a string

Tags: javascript

Multiple consecutive spaces are causing me a headache in my JS script. I tried doing this:

```js
const originalStr = 'Hello  there     how are  you'
const actual = originalStr.replace(/  /g, ' ')
const expected = 'Hello there how are you'

console.log(`originalStr = '${originalStr}'`)
console.log(`actual = '${actual}'`)
console.log(`expected = '${expected}'`)
console.log(`actual === expected ...`, actual === expected)
```

But as you can see it's not working. It's failing when there are 3 or more consecutive spaces. Is there a simple way to ensure that there are no consecutive spaces? TIA

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just modify your regex slightly:

```js
const originalStr = 'Hello  there     how are  you'
const actual = originalStr.replace(/ +/g, ' ')
const expected = 'Hello there how are you'

console.log(`originalStr = '${originalStr}'`)
console.log(`actual = '${actual}'`)
console.log(`expected = '${expected}'`)
console.log(`actual === expected ...`, actual === expected)
```

Comment: thanks so much - i was thinking id be stuck with a loop - much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

Edit your regex with `/ +/g`

```js
const originalStr = 'Hello  there     how are  you'
const actual = originalStr.replace(/ +/g, ' ')
const expected = 'Hello there how are you'
console.log(`originalStr = '${originalStr}'`)
console.log(`actual = '${actual}'`)
console.log(`expected = '${expected}'`)
console.log(`actual === expected ...`, actual === expected)
```